# How to manually populate the datagrid in asp.net 1.1 using vb.net 2003?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2003, asp.net-1.1

just would like to ask if it is possible to manually populate the datagrid in asp.net 2003 using vb.net

we usually populate the datagrid using this code, in this code what it does is it populate the datagrid base on your query , it's automated you can't edit or evaluate the data inside.

```
dataGrid.DataSource = ds
dataGrid.DataBind()
```

What if if I want to edit or evaluate the data inside the DataSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you link your `DataSource`, you can loop through it and modify the values if you want.  Try looping through the `ds.Tables("TableName").Rows` collection.

Comment: Thanks. though it's ds.Tables("TableName").Rows since it's VB thanks sir

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I updated my answer with the proper syntax, thanks.